# Images in npm package not displayed in Meteor app

Tags: meteor, npm, uploadcare

I'm trying to migrate some of my atmosphere packages to npm packages and ran into some issues with images not loading in the npm package [uploadcare-widget](https://github.com/uploadcare/uploadcare-widget).  The package references images in the folder `node_modules/uploadcare-widget/images`.  The images are displayed on the page via css, for example:

```
.uploadcare-dialog-file-sources:before {
  background-image: url("node_modules/uploadcare-widget/images/arrow.png");
}
```

I can see my app attempts to load the images from the network inspector, but the image doesn't load from the displayed path. I can confirm that image files are in the specified file directory.  Is there something special I need to do to be able to load images from an npm package?

I tried `import 'node_modules/uploadcare-widget/images';` and other variations inside the public folder.  I'll probably end up going back to using an atmosphere package :\

Comment: At the moment, you will probably need to copy them to the `public` folder. Note that the `public/` folder maps to the root, sot `public/foo.png` should be referred to as `/foo.png`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you use `UPLOADCARE_SCRIPT_BASE` like in [readme](https://github.com/uploadcare/uploadcare-widget/blob/master/README.markdown#using-with-npm), but maybe its wrong way.

Try to use just this code

```
import uploadcare from 'uploadcare-widget'
```

instead readme-like code.